# Trying to connect to SQL Server via astronomy - Apache Airflow

Tags: sql-server, airflow

I am trying to connect a SQL Server with Apache Airflow. I have used Astro to launch the container. I have added the connections under "Connections" in Airflow web UI. However, I am getting the following error.

```
pymssql._mssql.raise_MSSQLDatabaseException
pymssql._mssql.MSSQLDatabaseException: (20009, b'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (servername)\n')
```

Further, I cannot install pyodbc on astro. I am using Airflow version 2.2.0 and python 3.9.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. Trying to use pymssql on VS code allowed the connection to the MSSql server with just the server name. However, to achieve the with Airflow required me to enter servername.domainname under the host attribute in the Connections UI. This resolved the issue.

Comment: hey this might be a stupid question, but when you say domainname do you mean the schema? as in the servername.schema

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Please check this link to get the idea of domainname for windows authentication. https://help.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/20_0/on-premise/database-sql-server-domain-authentication.html